# Returning complex object from Jersey Rest

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I'm working on project where we are using Jersey Rest for Services. I have a Project class which has ArrayList of Activities.

```
    package com.test.services.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Project {


    public Project(){

        ArrayList<Activity> activities = new ArrayList<Activity>();

        Activity activity = new Activity();
        activity.setId("act1");
        activity.setName("Activity 1");

        activities.add(activity);

        activity = new Activity();
        activity.setId("act2");
        activity.setName("Activity 2");

        activities.add(activity);

        this.setActivities(activities);

    }


    private ArrayList<Activity> activities;

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="activities")
    public ArrayList<Activity> getActivities() {
        return activities;
    }

    public void setActivities(ArrayList<Activity> activities) {
        this.activities = activities;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="Codes")
    public ArrayList<String> getCodes() {

        ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();

        str.add("Hello");
        str.add("World");

        return str;
    }


    private int id;
}
```

and this is how my XML looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<projects>
    <project>
        <activities/> // Empty
        <activities/> //Empty
        <Codes>Hello</Codes>
        <Codes>World</Codes>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Project 1</name>
    </project>
    <project>
        <activities/>
        <activities/>
        <Codes>Hello</Codes>
        <Codes>World</Codes>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Project 2</name>
    </project>
    <project>
        <activities/>
        <activities/>
        <Codes>Hello</Codes>
        <Codes>World</Codes>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>Project 3</name>
    </project>
    <project>
        <activities/>
        <activities/>
        <Codes>Hello</Codes>
        <Codes>World</Codes>
        <id>4</id>
        <name>Project 4</name>
    </project>
</projects>
```

I have added empty ArrayList Codes ; to see if there is any problem with ArrayList's .I'm not sure why empty activities are returning in my XML .

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks,
R

Comment: I resolved it myself. Weird that I need to prepend my getters name with "get" .Like for Id I had to change it to getId.

Comment: The naming convetion for getters and setters is `getFoo()` and `setFoo(newFoo)`. Weird that you find that weird.

Comment: I was talking about, why I need to follow the naming convention even after I define my XML annotations on getters (in jersey rest), not about JAVA getters and setters in general.Thanks for your answer anyways